# Can I pass a method-name parameter to a method that can be used by a class or struct?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, struct

Currently I have this method:

```
 public void CreateDefaultTextPart(Func<string> methodName)
 {
    CreateTextPart("DefaultText.txt", (string text)  =>
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(string.Join("|", replacements.DefaultText().Keys.Select(x => Regex.Escape(x))));
        string replaced = regex.Replace(text, m => replacements.DefaultText()[m.Value]);
        return replaced;
    }
    );
 }
```

where `replacements` is a struct.

I have a bunch of these methods that is fairly similiar, only difference is the part of the code were the `replacement` struct is calling its methods. So instead of having to repeat the `CreateTextPart` method for every method that is in the struct I would like to just call a generic method name like this:

```
replacements.methodName()
```

Where `methodname()` can be any valid method that I pass in, that is existing in the struct.
So I then can pass in the `methodname` parameter directly into `CreateTextPart` , instead of having multiple methods doing basically the same thing.

Currently I am calling the methods like this:

```
  public void CreateTextFile()
  {
    CreateDefaultTextPart(SomeTestMethod); //"SomeTestMethod" is not used by any means here.
    CreateRedTextPart();
    CreateEndTextPart();
  }
```

And I would like to just do it like this if possible:

```
 public void CreateTextFile()
  {
    CreateDefaultTextPart(DefaultText);
    CreateDefaultTextPart(RedText);
    CreateDefaultTextPart(EndText);
  }
```

The resulting method should then look like this:

```
public void CreateDefaultTextPart(Func<string> methodName)
 {
    CreateTextPart("DefaultText.txt", (string text)  =>
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(string.Join("|", replacements.methodName().Keys.Select(x => Regex.Escape(x))));
        string replaced = regex.Replace(text, m => replacements.methodName()[m.Value]);
        return replaced;
    }
    );
 }
```

With a better suiting name of course.

I know that I can't use `Func` here like I'm doing but is it possible to achieve this in some other way?
Thanks!

Comment: yea, why not? its called callBack

Comment: @PhilM You realize that is for C++ and not the C# in this question, right?

Comment: Do all the methods in question return a `Dictionary<string,string>` ? What is the type of `replacements`? Do all the `struct`s have the same type?

Comment: Ah, failure to read tags, my old foe. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is one global `replacements` `struct` (??) and assuming the unspecified types, you can pass in a lambda to specify the member method to call.

```
public void CreatePart(Func<ReplacementMap, Dictionary<string, string>> getReplacementMap) {
    CreateTextPart("DefaultText.txt",
        (string text) => {
            var mapd = getReplacementMap(replacements);
            Regex regex = new Regex(string.Join("|", mapd.Keys.Select(x => Regex.Escape(x))));
            string replaced = regex.Replace(text, m => mapd[m.Value]);
            return replaced;
        }
    );
}
```

Then you just call `CreatePart` for each part:

```
public void CreateTextFile() {
    CreatePart(r => r.DefaultText());
    CreatePart(r => r.RedText());
    CreatePart(r => r.EndText());
}
```

But, why do all this when you can just pass in the method call result directly?

```
public void CreatePart(Dictionary<string, string> mapd) {
    CreateTextPart("DefaultText.txt",
        (string text) => {
            Regex regex = new Regex(string.Join("|", mapd.Keys.Select(x => Regex.Escape(x))));
            string replaced = regex.Replace(text, m => mapd[m.Value]);
            return replaced;
        }
    );
}

public void CreateTextFile() {
    CreatePart(replacements.DefaultText());
    CreatePart(replacements.RedText());
    CreatePart(replacements.EndText());
}
```